# Return Composite-type in Postgres C Function

Tags: c, postgresql

I have a user-defined type *mytype* :

```
CREATE TYPE mytype AS (
    value1 integer
);
```

I want to return mytype using C function. Here is what I have written :

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "funcapi.h"
#include "catalog/pg_type.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(testfunc);

Datum
testfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    TupleDesc   tupdesc;
    Datum       values[1];
    bool        nulls[1];

    MemSet(values, 0, sizeof(values));
    MemSet(nulls, 0, sizeof(nulls));

    tupdesc = CreateTemplateTupleDesc(1, false);
    TupleDescInitEntry(tupdesc, (AttrNumber) 1, "value1", INT4OID, -1, 0);

    tupdesc = BlessTupleDesc(tupdesc);

    values[0] = Int32GetDatum(100);

    HeapTuple rettuple = heap_form_tuple( tupdesc, values, nulls );
    PG_RETURN_DATUM( HeapTupleGetDatum( rettuple ) );
}
```

SQL reference :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunc() RETURNS mytype AS 'path/to/library.so', 'testfunc' LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

Now when I try to test my function, it crashes the connection :

```
postgres=# SELECT testfunc();
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

Please tell me where am I doing wrong.

Server Logs :

```
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST LOG:  server process (PID 25208) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT testfunc();
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-01-12 18:45:10 IST
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-01-12 18:47:45 IST LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2017-01-12 18:47:46 IST LOG:  record with zero length at 0/1C692E8
2017-01-12 18:47:46 IST LOG:  redo is not required
2017-01-12 18:47:46 IST LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-01-12 18:47:46 IST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-01-12 18:47:46 IST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

I have taken reference from [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#AEN60538) and [this](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/pgstatfuncs.c#L1869)

Comment: What is the error message in the server log?

Comment: included the server logs in the question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code; I just built it and it worked perfectly. That probably means the issue is with how you're compiling it. A minimal `Makefile` to compile `my_library_name.c` to `my_library_name.so` would look something like this: http://pastebin.com/i0YsJv0W (just make sure that `pg_config` is in your search path, or that its location is in `$PG_CONFIG`).

Comment: Even with this Makefile, session was still crashing on my Ubuntu **postgresql 9.3+154ubuntu1** version. So I build [postgres 9.3 stable from source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/REL9_3_STABLE) following this [link](http://big-elephants.com/2015-10/writing-postgres-extensions-part-iii/). And over there my function worked perfectly. Thanks for the help Nick.